# calculating total price of shopping cart before checkout

Tags: jquery

I'm doing a pizza web application where user can order food online, I want to calculate the total price with the specific size of pizza they've selected. I'm trying to use a switch case to equate a specific amount according to the size.

I've tried using the switch case but not achieving what I want

```
 function Pizza(size,topping,crust, name){
  this.size = size;
  this.topping = topping;
  this.crust = crust;
  this.name = name;
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#myform").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var sizep = $("#sizes option:selected").val();
    var topp = $("#toppings option:selected").val();
    var crustp = $("#crusts option:selected").val();
    var pname = $("#flavour option:selected").val();

    var small = $("#smal :selected").val();
    var medium = $("#medium :selected").val();
    var large = $("#large :selected").val();

    switch (sizep) {
      case small:
        price = 450;
        break;
      case medium:
        price = 750;
        break;
      case large:
        price = 1500;
        break;
      default:sizep

    }
    $("#total").append("Total:" + sizep.price);
  });
});
```

```
   <div class="flavour">
      <h6>Size</h6>
      <select class="input-group" id="sizes" name="Quantity">
         <option value="small">
           Small<span class="price">450</span> 
         </option>
         <option value="medium">
            Medium <span class="price">Ksh.750</span>
         </option>
         <option value="large">
           Large <span class="price">Ksh.1500</span>
         </option>
      </select>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion ther are some problems in the code.

- The selector to get the select options values isn't correct
- I don't understand where the var sizep.price is coming from...
- I dont' think it's necessary to get the options values to check them in the switch because you have to write them literraly to get the option value in the vars. In this way, check them directly in the switch.

According to you html i would have done something like that.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form#myform").submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var sizep = $("#sizes option:selected").val();
    var topp = $("#toppings option:selected").val();
    var crustp = $("#crusts option:selected").val();
    var pname = $("#flavour option:selected").val();

    var price = 0; 

    // not necessary but you can see how to select options val
    //var small = $('#sizes > select > option[value="small"]').val();
    //var medium = $('#sizes > select > option[value="medium"]').val();
    //var large = $('#sizes > select > option[value="large"]').val();

    switch (sizep) {
      case "small":
        price = 450;
        break;
      case "medium":
        price = 750;
        break;
      case "large":
        price = 1500;
        break;
      default:sizep

    }
    $("#total").append("Total:" + price);
  });
});
```

But in fact, to get further i this case i would have created a service with a function to get the pizza price or a property into the pizza class to calculate price accordingly to the size.

Regards

Comment: Thank you for the correction, I can see I had done multiple mistakes. It now prints the specific prize the price.

Comment: And if anyone has or knows good resources to help me learn javascript and jquery...please share. Thank you

Comment: i have used in the past [Jquery learning center](https://learn.jquery.com/) and [w3school jquery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/)